# Android action bar 'up' items, with activities that have more than one parent

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an Android app that uses the action bar, and the flow through the system is determined in the manifest as so:

```
<... android:parentActivityName="com.polymorph.amsmobile.xyzActivity" >
<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value="com.polymorph.amsmobile.xyzActivity" />
```

However there is a screen that users can go to from several points within the hierarchy and as such there is more than one 'parent' activity, so I want to dynamically specify the parent activity rather than specifying in the manifest.

My goal is to ensure that when they use the 'up' on the action bar, it will take them to the correct page of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this in an Activity from where you want to be able to go Up to another activitiy from the ActionBar?

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, GoToThisActivity.class);            
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
       startActivity(intent);
       return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I had the onOptionsItemSelected method already but was doing "NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);" instead of creating a new intent. Works great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to go to the previous activity, you can just do:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
      default:
        break;
    }
```